# Rails class naming collision

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, module, namespaces

In my rails application I have the following:

1. `Post` model

   ```
   class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
     # ...
   end
   ```
2. `Post` model inside such a module

   ```
   # lib/my_module/models.rb
   module MyModule
     module Models
       class AbstractTable < ActiveRecord::Base
         self.abstract_class = true
       end

       class Comment < AbstractTable
         belogs_to :post
       end

       class Post < AbstractTable
         has_many :comments
       end
     end
   end
   ```

Both `Post` models have different set of fields and are connected to different databases:

1. `Post` -> Postgresql adapter
2. `MyModule::Models::Post` -> SQLite adapter

**Sometimes** (depending on a seed value), when running test suite, I get a super strange constant (?) collition: in places, where original `Post` constant is mentioned (on a create/update operations) I get error that it lacks fields from `MyModule::Models::Post`, while in places, where `MyModule::Models::Post` is mentioned – I get an error that the model lacks attributes from origin `Post`.

Additional clues:

1. I only use `MyModule::Models::Post` inside the `MyModule` scope, calling `Models::Post`,
2. I never use `MyModule::Models::Post` outside the lib.
3. All "different" models are kept in a single file, `lib/my_module/models.rb`
4. If I login to a `pry` session for a failing spec, before the line where ruby brags about `MyModule::Models::Post` not having fields it should have (but fields from `Post` instead): calling `MyModule::Models::Post` returns me exact original `Post` model class!

**What am I missing? Is this an rspec problem? Am I messing up with convention or something?**

**Update 1**. I tried to split `Models` module, putting every additional model into a separate file. No luck – same errors

**Update 2**. Another thought was: since `Comment` model is defined before `Post`, Ruby tries to load original `Post` first. Still, moving the `Post` model up didn't help.

**Update 3**. RSpec had [this](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/commit/1e3f431e522d61b9b8df06e01c6bbcfff0e0981a) commit. Still, updating Gemfile's `rspec-mock` to point from github didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It you have **database A** and **database B**, that share some model names (though with completely different columns set), you have to make sure you reset column names after establishing the connection to the **database B**:

```
DatabaseBBaseTable.establish_connection(adapter: 'sqlite3', database: ':memory:')
@connection = DatabaseBBaseTable.connection
DatabaseBSchema.define(@connection)

DatabaseBBaseTable.descendants.each(&:reset_column_information)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should explicitly tell Rails what you expect:

```
 belongs_to :post, class_name: 'MyModule::Models::Post'
```

Comment: Unfortunately, didn't help :(